# Thinking in Java, 4th Edition, Generics Chapter

Tags: java, generics

In this chapter,in Arrays of generics topic the author says that all arrays have the same structure(size of each slot and array layout) regardless of the type they hold. I just want to know whether is it true or not ? I have also added the screenshot of that page!
[TIJ4 Generics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQgs5.png)

Comment: You do realise this is an ancient book? Anyway, it seems that he's talking about arrays of generics (which are, at bytecode level, all just objects) so it's true for those, but he mistakenly makes the assertion for *all* arrays.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a Java variable, that variable "is" just a pointer to a place in memory.  That place may contain a char or int value, or it may contain some instance of some Object.  But the variable itself, the "pointer", is always the same size, 16 bit, 32 bit, 64 bit, etc because all byte addresses in (16, 32, or 64 bit) memory can be reached by "pointers" of that size.

So with Java arrays, all that is really stored in the array itself is those "pointers" to the actual places in memory where the variables/objects collected in the array are stored.  Seen in this light, it makes perfect sense that "all arrays have the same layout and slot size" in Java.

Even if the statement doesn't cover all the edge cases any longer, it's a decently viable way of thinking about Java arrays (until you run into an edge case, and then this understanding will help you understand the edge case's differences from normal.)

Comment: Java variables of primitive type are not "pointers". Similarly, arrays of primitive type hold the data directly, and for instance a `char[3]` array takes much less space than a `long[3]`.

Comment: Agreed. But that's not what I said. "Pointers" is a loaded term.  When one writes `int j = 0;` that 'j' "points" to some place in memory where 4 consecutive bytes contain zero values.  In order to "point" to that 64 bit memory address, the "pointer" also needs to be 64 bits.  Yes, `char[3]` takes up much less space than `long[3]` because the char values are 1 byte and the long values are 8 bytes, but it takes the 4 exact same 64 bit sized "pointers" to address each of those 4 char or long values referenced in the array.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. If you say int j = 1234, the actual value 1234 (32 bits) goes directly into a place in memory labelled "j" by the compiler. There is no pointer at run-time that holds the address of where the value 1234 is stored. The compiler knows where it is (typically as a small offset from the stack pointer). It address, where required, is obtained directly from the byte code. Thus, when you have an array such as `char[] s = char[3]`, there are three consecutive 16-bit values; not three consecutive pointers to those values.

Comment: We're rolling into tomato tomato country.  You say, "a place in memory labeled 'j' by the compiler", but what is that label?  I say, it's "a pointer to a place in memory".  When we say `int j = 1234`, is 'j' the 32 bit value at some place in memory or is 'j' the 64 bit address of the place in memory where the 32 bit value is stored.  Tomato tomato.  IMHO, the "real" answer (for primitives) is kind-of-both.